# git status: fatal: .git/index: index file open failed: Unknown error 521

Tags: linux, git, nfs

I try to do `git status` and get:

```
fatal: .git/index: index file open failed: Unknown error 521
```

Another variant of this, when I do `git commit`, is this:

```
fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Unknown error 521
```

This probably is related to the directory being on a NFS share.
How can I solve this?

When I do the same then on another PC (using the same NFS share), it works. And then the error is also sometimes gone on the first PC. Also, when I just do `cat .git/index > /dev/null`, or `cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG > /dev/null`, this usually also fixes the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart`?

Comment: @slhck: I don't have root access. Also, there are about 50 other people here at the institute who would complain if suddenly their NFS share (with their home directories) is down.

Comment: Perhaps this info should be added to the question, including how the share is mounted etc. But if this is on a system which you cannot manage, have you spoken with the system administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a normal `ls` of the affected file, so `ls .git/index`, it will probably report `stale NFS file handle`, which can only be solved by restarting the NFS client on *that computer*. (so not affecting your entire department)

We see stale handles every few weeks/months in our own cluster environment. They seem to be caused by NFS server and client going out-of-sync due to spurious network problems, but our admins have not been able to pin it down. Restarting the NFS client (or lazily just the entire machine, in case of cookie-cutter cluster compute nodes) is the only fix that we are aware of.